# Relationship il Laravel 8 using three tables

Tags: laravel-8, relationship, between

Can some home help me to make this request using laravel Relationship?
`` SELECT * FROM `recoltes`, `plantations`, `users` WHERE recoltes.plantation_id = plantations.id AND plantations.user_id = users.id; ``

Answer (score 0):

Yes i found a way

````
public function recoltes ()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Recolte::class, Plantation::class);
}

Note that when i start with ```Plantation::class``` it does not work.
For that to work, You should specify how fields are related between tables
````